# Canon M50 will not record or take photos. How do I get the camera to work?

Tags: canon

Please help... Tried to record with my Canon eos M50 and nothing happens when I pressed the red record button. After that I tried using my shutter button to no avail. Next, I tried changing the SD card but the same issue remains. Oh by the way when I press the SHUTTER button, nothing! You guessed it! I can't take photos either.
The camera when it is turned to ON position, shows "the image" on the display screen, but nothing happens when I press the red record button. I have turned the camera to the ON and OFF positions as well and still nothing. Then, I've removed the battery and put it back in when I turned the camera to the OFF position, and again, not a thing happens when I press the red button. For your information I last recorded yesterday 8/12/22 just fine no issues. Any ideas? Yes I can navigate menus...

Comment: Can you navigate the menus?

Comment: Yes I can navigate the menus.

Comment: It started to freeze the display screen before record button stopped working. When I turned the camera off and on the camera stopped freezing the display screen, but the red record button and the shutter button would not work.

Comment: Did you try to reset it to factory settings using the menus?

Comment: Is the lens firmly and correctly attached? The camera default setting is that it won't open the shutter (aka take a photo) if it doesn't detect a lens, and if the lens is ever so slightly rotated out of position, it won't detect it. To check, simply take the lens off the camera, and reattach it.

Comment: If it is a lens that does not have electrical contacts, then you will have to select "shoot without lens" in the custom functions menu.